# How to show that two threshold graph having same spectra are isomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I have tried to show this by considering threshold graphs with less no of vertices. However not finding any pattern to show it in general.

Comment: A good start might be to understand the effect of adding an isolated vertex and a dominating vertex on the eigenvalues of the Laplacian / adjacency / your matrix of choice.